# [MX} -Inf dBm output when show interface diagnostics optics

Tags: juniper-mx

I've a problem when `show interfaces diagnostics optics <Ifd`. but the output for TX/RX = -Inf dBm.

Module is Fiberhome - XFP-10G-ER.

Junos: 17.3R3-S10.1

Link is UP, but it flaps many times. Log messages just about LFMD, log chassisd is normal.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Copy the text, past it into your question, and use the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`) that is right next to the image feature that you used. See [this meta question and answer](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2044/8499) about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems, that transceiver has died and needs to be replaced.

What you're describing might be due to fiber issues as well, but if the weird reading and the fiber flapping coincide, failure is the most  probable cause.

If you're not too sure about that, some cheap modules featuring DOM give funny readings from the start. I would stay clear of those.